# LAMP stacks for production use? Using PHP 5.4.x, Apache 2.4.x, MySQL 5.5.x

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Ok I thought I'd try installing the latest and greatest LAMP stack on my test server in preparation for using it in production. I decided to go with Ubuntu server 12.04, Apache (2.4.2), MySQL 5.5.24 and PHP 5.4.2 and use PHP-FPM/fast-cgi. I was then writing down the steps required into [an epic list](http://pastebin.com/0gRLeBYN) so I could replicate them easily when the time came to move to my production VPS.

- Ubuntu server installed no problems.
- I got Apache installed from source ok and it loaded the test page.
- MySQL compiled from source and installed
  fine. But then failed to run and I couldn't fix the mysql.sock error 
  so I gave up. Then I just did an `apt-get install mysql-server`
  which got me version 5.5.22 which is a few versions out of date but
  it runs properly so that's ok I suppose.
- So next comes PHP, that compiles, tests and installs fine. Now the
  final step: linking it in with Apache. And you can guess that it
  failed. It didn't compile with the necessary libphp5.so module so now
  that won't work. 'Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
  into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open
  shared object file: No such file or directory'.

Have google'd all these errors and tried fixing but getting nowhere. So have given up on the manual install for now as it's wasted two evenings so far.

1. Is there any decent LAMP stack that can be used in production?
2. Should you use one in production or should you really be installing
       everything manually? How does everyone get around this issue?
3. I know there's lots of LAMP stacks out there like XAMPP etc but they're never updated frequently and always a few versions behind. Why do they never keep them up to date?
4. Even when it's in production, how do you keep the installs up to date?

Also I suppose I could do apt-get to install everything. I love the one liner install but even those versions that get downloaded are way behind. Apache 2.4 would be nice for the speed improvements and I'm assuming it's best practice to keep up to date with PHP so you get the security enhancements.

Comment: Production machines are generally a few versions behind, because those versions are more likely then often proven stable.

Comment: I use stable repository installs so updates are less of hassle. I suspect this discussion might be better ontopic over at serverfault though? They have the expertice on this :)

Comment: Whoops yeah, it would be better on there, I'll post it over there Nanne, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everything works just fine for me, follow those tuts:

http://edin.no-ip.com/blog/hswong3i/apache-2-4-php5-4-pdo-oci-ubuntu-12-04-howto
http://www.ui3net.com/basic-installation-of-mysql-from-source/

;)

Comment: Thanks mate! I followed the first tutorial which got me up and running with Apache and PHP 5.4.5-dev. Then I installed MySQL using `apt-get install mysql-server` which got my 5.5.24 when you use the dotdeb repositories (linked above). To get MySQL going with PHP PDO I had to edit php.ini `pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. Also the mod_rewrite module wasn't turned on in the httpd.conf so enabled it `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. Works very well after that! I will pull down the stable versions of Apache and PHP from the website rather than from git.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use debian-testing but I hear that the dotdeb repository is a good choice.

http://www.dotdeb.org/

Comment: That seems pretty good. That'll work on Ubuntu as well I assume, seeing it's based on Debian?